# Passing Modal Array as parameters not passing data accuratelly Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, modal-dialog

Hey Everyone i am new to swift

i just want to pass a whole array which i populate from modal but when i pass it or print it, it shows ProjectName.ArrayName and memory-address
but not passing/printing the actual data. printing & parameters out pasted below

```
print array= [<HIT_IT_PRO.CategoryChecksList: 0x600003345360>, <HIT_IT_PRO.CategoryChecksList: 0x600003344c40>, <HIT_IT_PRO.CategoryChecksList: 0x600003345040>, <HIT_IT_PRO.CategoryChecksList: 0x600003344f20>]

params= [ "checks": [<HIT_IT_PRO.CategoryChecksList: 0x600003345360>, <HIT_IT_PRO.CategoryChecksList: 0x600003344c40>, <HIT_IT_PRO.CategoryChecksList: 0x600003345040>, <HIT_IT_PRO.CategoryChecksList: 0x600003344f20>]]
```

below is how i am populating array from model
`self.categoryChecks = CategoryChecksList.PopulateArray(array: ApiDataArray as! [[String : Any]])`

below is my `CAtegoryCheckList` file code

```
import Foundation

class CategoryChecksList: NSObject {
    
   
    var label:String = ""
    var checked:Bool = false
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
    }
    
    init(Data dictionary:[String: Any]){
        super.init()
        
        if let id1 = dictionary["checked"] as? Bool {
            checked = id1
        }
        
        if let label1 = dictionary["label"] as? String {
            label = label1
        }
        
    }
    
    class func Populate(dictionary:[String: Any]) -> CategoryChecksList {
        let obj = CategoryChecksList(Data: dictionary)
        return obj
    }
    
    class func PopulateArray(array:[[String: Any]]) -> [CategoryChecksList] {
        var result :[CategoryChecksList] = []
        for item in array {
            let obj = CategoryChecksList(Data: item)
            result.append(obj)
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to use print(array[0]);

Comment: @Kudos thanks but i want to pass whole array. i know print(array[0]) will print the actual data of 0 index

Comment: I think it is correct. After passing whole array. Just try to extract elements using for loop.

Comment: @Kudos but Api developer is saying provide data(in parameters) in actual printable form

Comment: In general, classes get printed like that whereas structs get their members printed. Show your relevant code and someone may be able to give you suggestions.

Comment: @jnpdx i add the relevant code

Comment: Why do you think it's not passing the data? NSObject will get printed like that (with the memory address). Either map the parameter you want and print that or use a struct if you want easy member wise printing

Comment: @jnpdx NSObject passing data when to display in tableview/print signle object but not displaying data when printing whole array....

Comment: What is your intended result? What do you expect to see in the console?

Comment: @jnpdx current output :  print array= [<HIT_IT_PRO.CategoryChecksList: 0x60000300d1c0>, <HIT_IT_PRO.CategoryChecksList: 0x60000300d700>, <HIT_IT_PRO.CategoryChecksList: 0x60000300da40>]                                                        Desired output: print array= [{“label”:”Floor”, checked:true}, {“label”:”Roof”, checked:false}, {“label”:”Hello”, checked:true}]

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, classes print the way that you're experiencing (with the module name, class name, and memory location). It doesn't mean that the data isn't getting passed to them correctly -- it's just how printing works.

To print the member data, you have a couple of options.

**Option 1**:

If you can have a `struct` instead of a class, you get this behavior for free. Of course, you may not be able to use a `struct` if your architecture depends on reference values or being a subclass of `NSObject` like you have.

```
struct CategoryChecksList{
    var label:String = ""
    var checked:Bool = false
    
    init(Data dictionary:[String: Any]){
        
        if let id1 = dictionary["checked"] as? Bool {
            checked = id1
        }
        
        if let label1 = dictionary["label"] as? String {
            label = label1
        }
        
    }
    
    static func Populate(dictionary:[String: Any]) -> CategoryChecksList {
        let obj = CategoryChecksList(Data: dictionary)
        return obj
    }
    
    static func PopulateArray(array:[[String: Any]]) -> [CategoryChecksList] {
        var result :[CategoryChecksList] = []
        for item in array {
            let obj = CategoryChecksList(Data: item)
            result.append(obj)
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

```
let list = [CategoryChecksList(Data: ["checked": true, "label": "Label"]),CategoryChecksList(Data: ["checked": false, "label": "Label2"]),CategoryChecksList(Data: ["checked": true, "label": "Label3"])]
                print(list)
```

prints:

```
[StackOverflowPlayground.CategoryChecksList(label: "Label", checked: true), StackOverflowPlayground.CategoryChecksList(label: "Label2", checked: false), StackOverflowPlayground.CategoryChecksList(label: "Label3", checked: true)]
```

**Option 2**:

Override `description` to specify how things should get printed. Add the following to your existing class:

```
override var description: String {
  "{label: \(label), checked: \(checked)}"
}
```

prints:

```
[{label: Label, checked: true}, {label: Label2, checked: false}, {label: Label3, checked: true}]
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply, i just got sick.... it's not working when passing array as parameters    let parameters = ["inspection_id": self.inspection_id,
                          "step_name": self.step_name,
                          "category": category,
                          "checks": categoryChecks ] as [String : Any]

Comment: i used your suggested approach struct, now my parameters are receiving in the following form :                                                   params= ["inspection_id": 1873, "category": "celling_struture", "step_name": "portfolio", "checks": [HIT_IT_PRO.CategoryChecksListt(label: "Joist", checked: false), HIT_IT_PRO.CategoryChecksListt(label: "Truss", checked: true), HIT_IT_PRO.CategoryChecksListt(label: "Rafters", checked: false), HIT_IT_PRO.CategoryChecksListt(label: "Other", checked: false), HIT_IT_PRO.CategoryChecksListt(label: "testing", checked: false)]]

Comment: I’m not following. Please describe how the output you’re getting is different from the output you want.

Comment: i just want that it(array) should receive in this format   "checks" = [
     {"label":  "Rafters", checked: false}
]    but it is receiving in this format.... response update cat check = SUCCESS: {
    check =     (
        "CategoryChecksListt(label: \"Aluminum\", checked: false)"
    );
}     ------- i don't know why it's printing CategoryChecksListt with array

Comment: Because if it's a struct, Swift prints the type along with it -- that's just how Swift works. Can I ask why you don't just print manually exactly the format that you want if it needs to be in an exact format? I gave you the system for doing that in option #2.